# Setting values of proprietary CaptureRequest keys in Camera2 API

Tags: android-camera2

I am building a simple camera app using `Camera2 API`. My mobile (`Xiaomi Redmi Note 7 Pro`) has a `Snapdragon 675` with `Qualcomm Spectra 250` as its `ISP`. According to the [specification](https://www.qualcomm.com/media/documents/files/snapdragon-675-mobile-platform-product-brief.pdf), this `ISP` has `Multi-Frame-Noise-Reduction` (`MFNR`) feature.

I have investigated the `CaptureRequest` object and found, that it has the following settings (the keys that don't start with *android* prefix is what I call *proprietary* in the question's title):

- `xiaomi.mfnr.enabled`
- `org.quic.camera2.mfnrconfigs.MFNRTotalNumFrames`

The `xiaomi.mfnr.enabled` is `null` by default, but I can set it to `1` (`new Byte[]{1}` due to this key's type), and in the `CaptureResult` object I see that this value is also present.

With this setting alone it's hard to notice any difference when taking photos in dim settings, thus I also tried to set `org.quic.camera2.mfnrconfigs.MFNRTotalNumFrames` to some value other than null, but no matter how I set it in the `CaptureRequest` (i.e. `new int[]{8}` due to its type), in the `CaptureResult` its value is set to `null`, so I assume that the `ISP` has ignored my setting.

I did try to use some other modes (night, HDR), various noise reduction modes (fast, high quality), control modes (off, auto), but the `org.quic.camera2.mfnrconfigs.MFNRTotalNumFrames` setting is still ignored.

Does anyone have any idea what should I do, to make my phone's ISP use that feature?

Comment: have you tried `new Int[]{8}` ?

Comment: I just tried with `new Integer[]{8}` - there's no difference. I assume that your intuition is that there was some confusion related to primitive vs non-primitive data types?